# Maths domain error in Python - don't know why?

Tags: python, math

I've received a maths domain error in Python and i have no idea what happened? Help would be appreciated

```
from math import *
def factors(A, B):
    a = 1
    b = B/A
    c = B
    x = ( -b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
    y = ( -b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
    return [x, y]

i = input('> ').split(',')
print(factors(int(i[0]), int(i[1])))
```

Comment: What python version are you using? What input are you giving? What is the exact error?

Comment: I'm not sure what version i'm using.

Comment: The input is on the second last line

Comment: The exact error is this:     x = ( -b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
ValueError: math domain error

Comment: @Gabriel: What numbers are you entering that cause the error?  I suspect that you're specifying values of `A` and `B` for which the argument to the square root is negative.

Comment: BTW, your use of `b = B/A` and `c = B` is a little odd.  You're effectively solving the quadratic equation `Ax^2 + Bx + AB = 0`.  Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Use b**2 instead of b*b. This is more pythonic.

Comment: @Sdwdaw: It's also less efficient, and potentially less accurate.  Though it's not as bad as using `b**0.5` instead of `sqrt(b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in apllying `sqrt` function to the negative numbers:

```
>>> sqrt(-4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Add some checking for negative:

```
if (b*b - 4*a*c) > 0:
    calculate
else:
    return False
```

Comment: I have done that and it come up with this error

Comment: 'from math import *'


'def factors(A, B):'
    a = 1'
    b = B/A
    c = B
    if (b*b - 4*a*c) > 0:
        x = ( -b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
        y = ( -b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
        return [x, y]
    else:
        return False


i = input('> ').split(',')
print(factors(int(i[0]), int(i[1])))

'

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how to comment code

Comment: from math import *


    def factors(A, B):
        a = 1
        b = B/A
        c = B
        if (b*b - 4*a*c) > 0:
            x = ( -b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
            y = ( -b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2*a
            return [x, y]
        else:
            return False


    i = input('> ').split(',')
    print(factors(int(i[0]), int(i[1])))

And it prints this out:

Comment: print(factors(int(i[0]), int(i[1])))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-7-6'

Comment: You forget to add coma between -7 and -6

Comment: It will be easier to split numbers into two inputs, like this `i1 = input('>Input A:\n')
i2 = input('>Input B:\n')
print(factors(int(i1), int(i2)))'

Answer (score 0):

If there are no real roots, you will be taking the square root of a negative number.

This is no problem if you use a `sqrt` that can return complex numbers

```
from cmath import sqrt
```